# Why is my service getting destroyed while mediaplayers are looping?

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer

In my App's MainActivity I am playing some sounds using MediaPlayers and in The onPause() in that activity I realease the players and I am starting a service to continue playing these sounds by creating them again and I send the resourcesNames and the Volume of every player from the activity to the service , I am using setLooping() to make these sounds loop and I am running the service in a new thread (outside the main thread) uding Handler and HandlerThread.
when the activity gets paused the service starts and the sounds are playing but the problem is  that they just loop for 3 times and then the service is getting destroyed without stopService() or stopSelf() are being called and also without exiting from the app(the app still in the recent apps)?

Here the sevice's code :

```
package com.example.naturesounds;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.Process;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SoundSPlayingService extends Service  implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
 {

  private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example.naturesounds";

  private float playerVolume = 0.0f;

  serviceHandler serviceHandler;

  Looper serviceLooper;

  HandlerThread thread;

  Intent intent;

  Bundle playersVolume = new Bundle() ;

  ArrayList<String> runningResourceNames = new ArrayList<>();

  HashMap<String, MediaPlayer> playersMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        
        thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceThread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

        thread.start();

        serviceLooper = thread.getLooper();

        serviceHandler = new serviceHandler(serviceLooper);
    }

    @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Message message = serviceHandler.obtainMessage();

        message.obj = intent;

        serviceHandler.sendMessage(message);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        releasePlayers();

        Log.d("serviceLifeCycle","onDestroy() is running");
    }

    public void createPlayer(String resourceName)
    {
        playersMap.put(resourceName,new MediaPlayer());

        try {
            playersMap.get(resourceName).setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),
            Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.naturesounds/raw/" + resourceName));

            playersMap.get(resourceName).setOnPreparedListener(this);

            playersMap.get(resourceName).prepareAsync();

            playersMap.get(resourceName).setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),                                            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

            setPlayerLooping(resourceName);

            setPlayerVolume(resourceName);
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e2)
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void releasePlayers()
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<runningResourceNames.size(); i++)
        {
            String resourceName = runningResourceNames.get(i);

            if(playersMap.get(resourceName) != null)
            {
                playersMap.get(resourceName).release();

                playersMap.put(resourceName,null);
            }
        }
    }

    public  void setPlayerVolume(String resourceName)
    {
        playerVolume = playersVolume.getFloat(resourceName);

        Log.d("playerVolume",String.valueOf(playerVolume));

        playersMap.get(resourceName).setVolume(playerVolume,playerVolume);
    }

    public void setPlayerLooping(String resourceName)
    {
        playersMap.get(resourceName).setLooping(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mp.start();
    }


    class serviceHandler extends Handler
  {
      public serviceHandler(Looper looper)
      {
          super(looper);
      }

      @Override
      public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {

          Log.d("serviceHandlerChecking","handleMessage() is executing");

          intent = (Intent) msg.obj;

          runningResourceNames = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(PACKAGE_NAME +                             ".MainActivity.runningResourceNames");

          playersVolume = intent.getBundleExtra(PACKAGE_NAME + ".MainActivity.playersVolume");

          for(int i=0; i<runningResourceNames.size(); i++)
          {
              String resourceName = runningResourceNames.get(i);

             createPlayer(resourceName);
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what Android API version are you using?

Comment: Your service needs to be in foreground (with notification), I believe system doesn't allow media sessions from background apps to be active.

Comment: @dmtr if your asking about the api that i tried my app on its api 28 but my app's minimum sdk is api 16

Comment: @ok I need my service to be foreground and to run a notification but i faced this problem before writing the codes for that, now i will do that and see if the problem will be solved, thanks

Comment: starting from Nougat there is a doze mode, and from Oreo we got even more strict rules for services. as @Pawel said you need to show notification and it should be foreground.